# Shortcut key CTRL+F1 bug in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

When trying to assign sp_helptext (or any other shortcut) to CTRL+F1 in SQL server 2012, microsoft help viewer keeps popping up.  Has anyone else encountered this bug in 2012?  Is their a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked that Control-F1 is assigned to `Query.CustomSP1` in Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard | Keyboard?

(The Environment | Keyboard | Query Shortcuts dialog just associates the shortcuts with commands, which are separately associated with keys – the former part of options.)